# Python Index out of range for the below syntax

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to troubleshoot an existing code and having hard time to fugure what is causing to this all of sudden, it has been working fine for 1 year and now this fails

code where it is failing. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
astl_mod = [x for i,x in enumerate(lastl_mod) if i != len(lastl_mod)-1 and lastl_mod[i+1][1] != x[1]] + [lastl_mod[-1]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Depending on the value on the value of `lastl_mod`, `x` may no longer have 2 or more elements, making `x[1]` the culprit. (Same goes for `lastl_mod[i+1][1]`.)

Comment: @chepner, thank you i added this to the code and it seem to be working now. Please advise if it makes sense and is the right way to debug this 
 if len(lasth_mod) == 0:
       lasth_mod = [[np.nan]]

    if len(lastl_mod) == 0:
       lastl_mod = [[np.nan]]

Answer (score 0):

There are too many places for you to review. If you don't mind, please post an example of lastl_mod for everyone so that we can know what its format looks like.

Bullet points:

- Make sure lastl_mod is NOT an empty list. I know you won't want that either, the thing is some tiny errors within your codes sometimes will cause the things like that.
- Make sure the length of the element of lastl_mod is at least 2.

Personally, I suggest you break down the codes, like, rewrite this into for-loop instead of one-line, that really helps you when debugging.